# Trim a string in c# to go from this = 1:"Transmitters" to this = Transmitters

Tags: c#, string, trim

I want to trim a string that looks like this 1:"Transmitters" and i want it to look like this = Transmitters.

Comment: K, sooo...what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: `var str = @"1:""Transmitters""".Substring(3, 12);`

Comment: Form the variations of answers you are getting it seems it's unclear if the literal "this" is part of the input and output. You should format your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take the title literally:

```
str = str.Trim('1',':','"');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string with ':' and remove the quotes.

```
var str = "1:""Transmitters""";
var output = str.Split(':')[1].Replace("""","");
```

or you can also use Regular Expressions ([Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.90).aspx) class).

Answer (score 1):

To extract between quotes

```
int pos = str.IndexOf('"');
str = str.Substring(pos + 1, str.Length - pos - 2);
```

Comment: But if any character appears after second quote...

Comment: Then `str = str.Substring(pos + 1, str.IndexOf('"', pos + 1) - pos - 1);`

Answer (score 0):

If the chracters that you want to remove always has the same size, you can just use the `Substring` method:

```
string s = "1:\"Transmitters\"";
s = s.Substring(3, s.Length - 4);
```

If the number before the colon can change, look up the psoition of the colon in the string:

```
string s = "123:\"Transmitters\"";
int pos = s.IndexOf(':');
s = s.Substring(pos + 2, s.Length - pos - 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
string temp = "1:\"Transmitters\"";
temp = temp.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Split(':')[1];
```